# Most optimal topological sort

Tags: python, algorithm

I found a solution to this topological sorting question, but it's not a solution I came across in any of my research, leading me to believe it's not the most optimal. The question (from algoexpert) reads along the lines of: "return one of the possible graph traversals given a graph where each node represents a job and each edge represents that job's prereq. First param is a list of numbers representing the jobs, second param is a list of arrays (size 2) where the first number in the array represents the prereq to the job being the second number. For example, inputs([1,2,3], [[1,3],[2,1],[2,3]]) => [2, 1, 3]. Note: the graph may not be acyclical, which the algorithm should then return an empty array. Example, inputs([1,2], [[1,2],[2,1]]) => [].

A popular optimal solution is a bit confusing to me, as I've tried implementing it, but keep getting situations where my algorithm detects a cycle and short-circuit returns an empty array. This algorithm "works backwards" in a depth-first manner, with "in-progress" and "visited" nodes kept in memory while searching the graph.

My algorithm initially finds graph nodes with no prereqs (as these can be immediately added to the return array), and removes this node from all other nodes prereqs. While this removal happens, if this node now has 0 prereqs, add it to the stack. When the stack size reaches 0, return the return array if its size matches the size of the first param (jobs list), otherwise return an empty array, which in this case means that a cycle was present in the graph. Here's the code for my algorithm:

```
def topologicalSort(jobs, relations):
    rtn = []
    jobsHash = {}
    stackSet = set()
    for job in jobs:
        stackSet.add(job)
    for relation in relations:
        if relation[1] in stackSet:
            stackSet.remove(relation[1])
        if relation[0] not in jobsHash:
            jobsHash[relation[0]] = {"prereqs": set(), "depends": set()}
        jobsHash[relation[0]]["depends"].add(relation[1])
        if relation[1] not in jobsHash:
            jobsHash[relation[1]] = {"prereqs": set(), "depends": set()}
        jobsHash[relation[1]]["prereqs"].add(relation[0])
        if jobsHash[relation[0]]["prereqs"].__contains__(relation[1]):  # 2 node cycle shortcut
            return []
    stack = []
    for job in stackSet:
        stack.append(job)
    while len(stack):
        job = stack.pop()
        rtn.append(job)
        clearDepends(jobsHash, job, stack)
    if len(rtn) == len(jobs):
        return rtn
    else:
        return []


def clearDepends(jobsHash, job, stack):
    if job in jobsHash:
        for dependJob in jobsHash[job]["depends"]:
            jobsHash[dependJob]["prereqs"].remove(job)
            if not len(jobsHash[dependJob]["prereqs"]):
                stack.append(dependJob)
        jobsHash[job]["depends"] = set()


print(topologicalSort([1,2,3,4],[[1,2],[1,3],[3,2],[4,2],[4,3]]))
```

I found this algorithm to have a time complexity of O(j + d) and space complexity of O(j + d), which is on par to the popular algorithms attributes as well. My question is, did I find the correct complexities, and is this an optimal solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is Kahn's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm